# How to use functions from another module in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS by making a Todo list app. However, I can't figure out how to use modules from one another.

In detail, I have this code in my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'TodoItem'
    ]);

var TodoItem = angular.module( 'TodoItem' );
app.init = function () {
    var item1 = TodoItem.newItem();
    item1.title = 'Item 1';
    var item2 = TodoItem.newItem();
    item2.title = 'Item 2';

    app.todoList = [ item1, item2
    ];
}

app.init();
```

The module `TodoItem` is from `TodoItem.js`, which is:

```
'use strict';

var TodoItemModule = angular.module('TodoItem', []);

function TodoItemClass() {
    this.id = -1;
    this.title = '';
    this.detail = '';
    this.endDate = null;
    this.startDate = null;
}

TodoItemModule.newItem = function() {
    return new TodoItemClass();
}
```

In the `index.html` of the app, I have the following code:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/todo.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/models/TodoItem.js"></script>
```

which I believe doesn't have misspelling in it.

However, I get this error in Chrome Javascript console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'TodoItem' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/nomod?p0=TodoItem
```

So, what did I do wrong here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TodoItem.js is required for app.js, it will need to be loaded beforehand.

It looks like you create TodoItem module, but you'll need to register any services you want to use inside of it.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module/#configuration-blocks, and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services.

Then, as a result of indicating TodoItem as a dependency of todoApp, you'll have access to all of the services registered in TodoItem in any services, controllers, or filters you register in todoApp.

Comment: Glad this can be helpful -- I'll add that two great architectural starting points can be found via the angular developers themselves: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed, and via Yeoman: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to load `scripts/models/TodoItem.js` before `scripts/app.js`

But your approach is little out of angular's architecture. Instead of creating a class TodoItemClass, I'd recommend you to make use of angular's built it services ([link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)).

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use AngularJS as if it were RequireJS.  Including other modules in your module/app does not add their class objects to your code.  Rather, including outside modules exposes the services/controllers/directories/etc that the module defines to your module, so that they can be injected into YOUR services/controllers/etc.

In fact, none of the code samples you show above actually do anything with Angular.  If you are simply looking for a modularized AMD-style dependency manager than go with RequireJS.  If you are building controllers/directives/services/factories as a single-page application then you need to start building those components within your modules.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers address the conceptual problems with your current code and how AngularJS is used. I thought I'd offer you a little code snippet to show a basic example of what they mean.

TodoItem.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var todoItem = angular.module('TodoItem', []);

todoItem.service('todoItemSvc', [function() {
  var service = {};

  function TodoItemClass() {
    this.id = -1;
    this.title = '';
    this.detail = '';
    this.endDate = null;
    this.startDate = null;
  }

  service.newItem = function() {
    return new TodoItemClass();
  }

  return service;

}]);

})();
```

app.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('todoApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'TodoItem'
    ]);

app.controller('RootCtrl', ['$scope','todoItemSvc', function($scope,todoItemSvc) {
  var item1 = todoItemSvc.newItem();
  item1.title = 'Item 1';
  var item2 = todoItemSvc.newItem();
  item2.title = 'Item 2';

  $scope.todoList = [item1, item2];
}]);

})();
```